# Laravel Single Table Model Inheritance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `Article`, which is extended by `Post`, `News`, etc. When I call Eloquent methods such as `all()` on these subclasses, I'd like them to filter results by `__CLASS__`. The plural, lowecase version of classname would be stored in the articles table in a certain enum field `type`. At the moment calling `Post::all()` I get everything, including news articles.

Is there Laravel-specific solution, that I don't have to override the whole Eloquent functionality?

**Articles**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

abstract class Article extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'articles';


    // TODO filter eloquent results by article type ( classname ) 

}
```

**News**

```
<?php

namespace App\Article;

class News extends \App\Article{


}
```

> // I'm using Laravel 5, the latest dev version from master branch.

Comment: Global scope is the Laravel way - http://softonsofa.com/laravel-how-to-define-and-use-eloquent-global-scopes/

Answer (score 0):

Found that Laravel has a built-in function `newQuery` to override QueryBuilder functionality. This made things a hell lot easier.

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

abstract class Article extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function __construct($attributes = array()){
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        $this->setAttribute('class_name',get_class($this));
    }

    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true){

        $builder = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);

        if ('Article' !== get_class($this)) {
            $c = get_class($this);
            $c = explode('\\', $c);
            $c = end($c);
            $builder->where('type',"=", $c);
        }

        return $builder;

    }

}
```

I needed explode because of the namespace notation.